# How does one unit test handling of the error conditions for Python/C APIs like PyType_Ready and PyObject_New?

Tags: python, c, unit-testing

It's fairly straightforward (if tedious) to unit test Python extension modules written in C, including the error cases for many of the Python/C APIs such as PyArg_ParseTuple.  For example, the idiomatic way to start a C function which implements a Python function or method looks like:

```
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "someformat:function_name")) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

The success case of this can be unit tested by calling the function with the correct number and type of arguments.  The failure cases can also be tested by calling the function with first the wrong number of arguments and then the right number of arguments but passing values of the wrong type.  This results in full branch test coverage of the C code.

However, it's not clear how to exercise the negative paths for other Python/C APIs.  An idiomatic way to begin module initialization in a C extension looks like:

```
    if (PyType_Ready(&Some_Extension_Structure) < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
```

How can `PyType_Ready` be made to fail?  Similarly, the C function for allocating a new instance of an extension type frequently uses an API like `PyObject_New`:

```
    self = PyObject_New(Some_Structure, &Some_Extension_Structure);
    if (self == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

How can one unit test this negative case (particularly considering `PyObject_New` is likely used many, many times over the course the execution of a single unit test method)?

It seems possible to build a general solution, relying on dynamic linker tricks such as `LD_PRELOAD` to provide fakes of these C APIs which can be directed to fail in the right ways at the right times.  The cost of building a system like that seems a bit out of reach, though.  Has someone else done it already and make the result available?

Are there Python/C-specific tricks that could make this testing easier?

Should I be thinking along some other lines entirely?

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear case for test doubles (for example, mocking).  Since the Python C API doesn't offer any facilities for faking an out of memory condition, you'd have to do it yourself.

Create your own layer that provides `PyType_Ready` and `PyObject_New`.  Have them pass through to the C API functions, unless some control, probably an environment variable, instructs them not to.  They can cause any mayhem you desire, and test your code's reaction.

Comment: Thanks Ned.  The trouble with test doubles is that C is not very amenable to the "monkey patching" that's so simple in Python and the Python/C API seems to provides no way to inject alternate implementations either.  If I'm going to go down this route, I need a special multi-process test runner that can abuse the linker appropriately; I need a way to determine the calling context in each fake function (so I only abuse my own code, not the rest of the Python runtime), etc.  I can see it, but the road looks long and hard...  I really want some clever solution that's more within reach. :/

Comment: Yes, C is brittle like that.  I meant that you'd write a function that either called PyType_Ready, or returned an error, based on the environment variable.  You'd have to mix that "test double" code into your real code, and leave it there always.  Not as elegant as a true test double, but would let you test your code.